# linux live kit work trouble on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: virtualbox, compiling, iso

Can someone please help me? I am having trouble getting Linux live kit to work. First I went and found the latest release. Then I downloaded it. Extracted the file. Then inside the file, there is a folder and inside that folder, there were all the files that I dropped into tmp. Then I ran all the commands. After the build was done I went into the data folder and ran the command to build the iso file. But when I upload it to a VM it won't boot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. First, what Ubuntu are you using? What is the host machine and what is the guest? Where did you download from? What exactly did you download? What files? What "all commands" did you run? What is the command to "build the iso file"? How do you "upload to the VM"? How does it "not boot"? Any errors?Please add all this to your question so we can understand what you are doing and how it failed.

Comment: Sorry, I am using ubuntu 20.04 I am using a vm, I downloaded it from release.ubuntu.vom, Downloaded an iso file, file name ubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso, I ran sudo -i, cd /tmp, sudo ./build, then I went into the data folder and ran, a command that I cant find to build the iso file. It shows up in tmp, just wont boot. I used this to help me learn to build the file, https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/make-a-custom-live-linux-distro-with-linux-live-kit/

Comment: Yes, as I asked before, please EDIT your question to include the extra information.